# Create a function to extract specific columns and rename pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a target table structure (3 columns). I have multiple sources, each with its own nuances but ultimately I want to use each table to populate the target table (append entries)

I want to use a function (I know I can do it without a function but it will help me out in the long run to be able to use a function)

I have the following source table

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4 
1   a    b    c    g
1   a    b    d    h
1   c    d    e    i
```

I want this final structure

```
id num  group  
1   a    b    
1   a    b    
1   c    d
```

So all I am doing is returning id, col1 and col2 from the source table (but note the column name changes. For different source tables it will be a different set of 3 columns that I will be extracting hence the use of a function).

The function I am using is currently returning only 1 column (instead of 3)

Defining function:

```
def func(x, col1='id', col2='num', col3='group'):
    d=[{'id':x[col1], 'num':x[col2], 'group':x[col3]}]
    return pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Applying the function to a source table.

```
target= source.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a flexible way to write this function:

```
def func(dframe, **kwargs):
    return dframe.filter(items=kwargs.keys()).rename(columns=kwargs)

func(df, id="id", col1="num", col2="group")

#   group  id num
# 0     b   1   a
# 1     b   1   a
# 2     d   1   c
```

To ensure that your new dataframe preserves the column order of the original, you can sort the argument keys first:

```
def func(dframe, **kwargs):
    keys = sorted(kwargs.keys(), key=lambda x: list(dframe).index(x))
    return dframe.filter(items=keys).rename(columns=kwargs)

func(df, id="id", col1="num", col2="group")

#    id num group
# 0   1   a     b
# 1   1   a     b
# 2   1   c     d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
def func(df, *l):
    d = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=l)
    d.rename(columns={'col1':'num', 'col2':'group'}, inplace=True)
    return d

df2 = func(df, 'id','col1','col2')

print(df2)

   id num group
0   1   a     b
1   1   a     b
2   1   c     d
```